# Как преобразовать массив объектов в AR::Relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Знаю что это неправильные действия изначально, но все же, другого выхода в моем случае не вижу.
Есть товары - модель `Items`(таблица `items`).
Цена на них строится динамически - модель `PriceItems` (таблицы нет).

Нужно сделать сортировку товаров по цене, делаю

```
@products.map do |product|
        price = @prices["#{product.make_name}-#{product.oem}"] #здесь получаю цену конкретного товара
        if price.present?
          [price.cost, product]
        end
      end
```

Получается такой массив:
`[[6845, #<Product id: 1], [6345, #<Product id: 2], [4742, #<Product id: 3], [6045, #<Product id: 4]]`

Дальше делаю:

```
j = s.sort_by {|h| h[0]} # сортирую по цене
w = j.each {|el| el.delete_at(0)} # удаляю цену и получаю [[#<Product id: 3], [#<Product id: 4], [#<Product id: 2], [#<Product id: 1] ]
@sort_products = w.flatten #Получаю массив с объектами [#<Product id: 3, #<Product id: 4, #<Product id: 2, #<Product id: 1]
```

В общем получаю массив объектов, как его преобразовать в массив объектов `ActiveRecord::Relation`?

На самом деле я делаю `Items.where(id: @sort_products.map(&:id))`, но возвращает это `AR:Relation` отсортированный по `id` (т.е. вернулся к первоначальному состоянию)

Comment: По-хорошему, никак, т. к. AR::R определяет способ доставания данных из БД; а если это массив, то данные уже покинули БД и лежат в памяти. Но зачем именно вам это нужно? Что вы хотите потом с этим Relation'ом сделать?

Comment: например пагинацию `.page(params[:page]).per(per_page)` (kaminari). метод page работает с relation

Comment: Если вы уже все данные загрузили в память, разбиением на страницы заниматься немножко поздно :) Kaminari как раз задействует средства БД, чтобы **не** загружать весь набор данных, а загружать только необходимое (плюс константное количество дополнительного). Но даже если об этом забыть, для массива это ведь тривиально пишется без всяких гемов.

Comment: Но нужно выводить уже отсортированные товары с пагинацией.

Comment: Просто я не вижу выхода, т.к. цен у меня нет в базе. они берутся из прайса. Я получаю массив с товарами, по артикулу ищу цену (итерация из тела вопроса), так я соотношу товар и цену. Дальше сортирую как мне нужно и удаляю цену. Получаю правильно (как мне нужно) отсортированный массив.

Comment: Если вы уверены, что это не косяк дизайна, [читайте документацию к Kaminari](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari#paginating-a-generic-array-object).